# How to avoid exposing Api keys in environment.ts?

Tags: reactjs, angular, environment-variables, obfuscation, .env

I'm Looking for ways to hide API keys in the frontend of React or Angular. In React, I used an .env file and process.env, but still, it is accessible when I open the browser console under source even after running the built project. In Angular, I used environment.ts, which is still exposed.

Is there any way to achieve client-side restrictions? not to directly view the tokens in browser->source->bundle. I did obfuscation, which at least added some code complexity to find the token.